# Form has submited the value to be displayed in array format using PHP array method

Tags: php, arrays, forms

To get the values of the form and displayed in array format.

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$a=explode(" ",$name);
$b=explode(" ",$email);
$combined = array_merge($a, $b);
print_r($combined);
}
```

In this code the output as like this:

```
Array ( [0] => rag [1] => raj )
```

But I have the output like this form name as the index:

```
Array ( [name] => rag [email] => raj )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change

```
$a=explode(" ",$name);
$b=explode(" ",$email);
$combined = array_merge($a, $b);
```

to

```
$combined = array(
'name'=>$name,
'email'=>$email
)
```

This will provide the data that you want using the keys `name` and `email`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to construct it manually since `explode` expects a delimiter and a string, it has no connection to your post variables. Also, if the explode finds spaces it will split them and you'll have a multi dimentional array to handle:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        print_r([
            'name' => explode(' ', $_POST['name']),
            'email' => explode(' ', $_POST['email']),
        ]);
    }
?>
```

Possible outputs could be:

### 1

**input**

`$_POST['name']` = 'Sidney Liebrand';

`$_POST['email']` = 'someone@email.com';

**output**

```
[
    'name' => ['Sidney', 'Liebrand'],
    'email' => ['someone@email.com']
]
```

### 2

**input**

`$_POST['name']` = 'Sidney';

`$_POST['email']` = 'someone@email.com';

**output**

```
[
    'name' => ['Sidney'],
    'email' => ['someone@email.com']
]
```

These are just two of the possible outcomes you'll have to work with in this situation.